# Display Bug when trying to load LobbyScreen on SOME devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore, networkmanager

We're trying to access the LobbyScreen from the Unity Network Manager via a button.
The Lobby itself loads fine in scenes where we didn't change anything. In one scene though we changed some sprites and added some Text.
Since then, when that lobbyscreen gets loaded, the background is mostly black with white stripes (on Google Pixel 2 with Android 10) [DisplayBug on GooglePixel2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYaFP.jpg). The unchanged LobbyScreens still load normally.
When I tried the same scene with two different Samsung smartphones there were no issues, the scene loaded the way it is supposed to.

We're on Unity 2018.4.20f

I'm sure I only changed some design aspects. Does anyone know why this only happens on some smartphones or what I can change to make it work on the other phones as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone stumbles upon this with the same problem:

For me it was the camera settings. I'm going to attach a screenshot with the settings it suddenly worked for us.
[Correct settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zhm1.png)
The main issue seemed to be the Skybox.